# How to replace &apos ($song[1]) with a single quote

Tags: php, twitter

```
$twitterObj->post('/statuses/update.json', 
    array('status' => '#NowPlaying ' . $song[1] . 
        ':: Metal Rock 1970 - 2000 - http://metalrockpopradio.caramania.com'));
?>
```

Comment: can u add the question to the text? what do you mean with `&apos`, the actual `&` or the string `&apos` ?

Comment: exemple: when i tweet the result is Boston - D&apost look back but i want Boston - Don't look back

Comment: Please update you question with some examples of the result you're getting, expect and what you've tried. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want that string gone:

```
$song[1] = str_replace('&apos','', $song[1]);
```

To replace with a quote

```
$song[1] = str_replace('&apos',"'", $song[1]);
```

If `&apos;` had a semicolon at the end you could do:

```
$song[1] = html_entity_decode($song[1], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5);
```

Place this line above the $twitterObj->post

Also isn't that &apos missing a ; at the end?